# Multiplexing control files error

Tags: oracle, startup

We can create only 8 control files.

If I create 9 files, I should get the error:
ORA-00208: number of control file names exceeds limit of 8.

But I get the error ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel.

Why not ORA-00208?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens is that the backend attempts to start in response to the `startup` command you supplied in SQL*Plus. That fails -- logging an error in alert.log -- and SQL*Plus loses its connection with the backend, so you receive the end-of-file on communication channel error.

In SQL*Plus:

```
SQL> startup pfile='C:\more_ctlfiles.ora'
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area 2.1206E+10 bytes
Fixed Size                 19897816 bytes
Variable Size            2818572288 bytes
Database Buffers         1.8321E+10 bytes
Redo Buffers               47210496 bytes
ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel
Process ID: 19528
Session ID: 607 Serial number: 8502
```

In the alert log file:

```
ALTER DATABASE   MOUNT
2020-01-19T11:06:24.896505-06:00
Errors in file C:\APP\ORACLE\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\trace\orcl_ckpt_22600.trc:
ORA-00208: number of control file names exceeds limit of 8
Errors in file C:\APP\ORACLE\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\trace\orcl_ckpt_22600.trc  (incident=860698) (PDBNAME=CDB$ROOT):
ORA-208 [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] []
Incident details in: C:\APP\ORACLE\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\incident\incdir_860698\orcl_ckpt_22600_i860698.trc
2020-01-19T11:06:27.070718-06:00
USER (ospid: ): terminating the instance due to ORA error 
2020-01-19T11:06:27.084396-06:00
System state dump requested by (instance=1, osid=22600 (CKPT)), summary=[abnormal instance termination].
System State dumped to trace file C:\APP\ORACLE\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\trace\orcl_diag_24248.trc
2020-01-19T11:06:30.323367-06:00
Instance terminated by USER, pid = 22600
```